# netbeans platform NotificationDisplayer close button action performed

Tags: netbeans-platform

i am using the netbeans RCP,i used a baloon dialog at status bar to display when i first login using NotificationDisplayer . 
Link Button acton perform is working fine. 
but i want to display warning dialog when i click on close button (i.e., cross button)of NotificationDisplayer.

Thanks, 
Gaddam

Answer (score 0):

I was trying use DialogDIsplayer and DIalogDescriptor to create login dialog too. But now I know, that this way has some stupid problem with testing this dialog via Jemmy or Jelly testing tools.

So I change way.
1) I create TopComponent, that is open on start, no dragable, no closeable etc and all unnecessary my module changed to type "autoload". when the user logs in, then turn on the required modules programmatically.

Jirka